# Rails 5 - Nested Model Form Not Saving Child Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I've been at this problem for a couple weeks now on and off.

Currently I have a User model, Employee model and an Employee_Contact model. The User model was generated using Devise. After the User is logged in they can go to their User Dashboard and create an Employee using a nested form. I am having an issue where the child model Employee_Contact is not saving into the database.

Schema:

```
  create_table "employee_contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "street"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "phone_num"
    t.string "alt_phone_num"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "emergency_contact_first_name"
    t.string "emergency_contact_last_name"
    t.string "emergency_contact_num"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "employee_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["employee_id"], name: "index_employee_contacts_on_employee_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_employee_contacts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "middle"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "sex"
    t.string "race"
    t.date "birthdate"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "employee_contact_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_employees_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: 
    "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    end
  end
```

These are my models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :employees, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :employee_contact, inverse_of: :employee, autosave: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_contact, allow_destroy: true
end

class EmployeeContact < Employee
  belongs_to :employee, inverse_of: :employee_contact
end
```

My Employee Controller:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  def create
    @employee = current_user.employees.create(employee_params)

    if @employee.save!
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
 end

 private

 def employee_params
   params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :middle, :last_name, 
   :sex, :race, :birthdate, employee_contact: [:id, :street, :city, 
   :state, :zip, :phone_num, :email, :alt_phone_num, 
   :emergency_contact_first_name, :emergency_contact_last_name, 
   :emergency_contact_num])
   end
 end
```

My View Form:

```
      <%= form_with(model: @employee, local: true) do |form| %>
      <h3>Employee Profile Information</h3>

      <%= form.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= form.text_field :first_name %><br />

      <%= form.label :middle %><br />
      <%= form.text_field :middle %><br />

      <%= form.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= form.text_field :last_name %><br />

      <%= form.label :sex %><br />
      <%= form.text_field :sex %><br />

      <%= form.label :race %><br />
      <%= form.text_field :race %><br />

      <%= form.label :birthdate %><br />
      <%= form.date_field :birthdate %><br />

      <h3>Employee Contact Information</h3><br />

      <%= form.fields_for :employee_contacts do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.label :street %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :street %><br />

        <%= builder.label :city %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :city %><br />

        <%= builder.label :street %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :street %><br />

        <%= builder.label :state %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :state %><br />

        <%= builder.label :zip %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :zip %><br />

        <%= builder.label :phone_num %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :phone_num %><br />

        <%= builder.label :alt_phone_num %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :alt_phone_num %><br />

        <%= builder.label :email %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :email %><br />

        <%= builder.label :emergency_contact_first_name %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :emergency_contact_first_name %><br />

        <%= builder.label :emergency_contact_last_name %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :emergency_contact_last_name %><br />

        <%= builder.label :emergency_contact_num %><br />
        <%= builder.text_area :emergency_contact_num %><br />
      <% end %>
      <%= form.submit "Add", class: 'btn btn-primary' %><br />
    <% end %>
```

When I get submit the form to create a new employee this is what I get in my console parameters:

Processing by EmployeesController#create as HTML
Parameters:{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"IgYzybxM8+M8jZ8NJgYKZ+Zhqr07kcV1e0QyWf> uY8hQLyBY844jfOlLNl65F/2RRr4TTW0F1MeSmDzVzBsXOjg==", "employee"=>
{"first_name"=>"Firt Nam", "middle"=>"kk", "last_name"=>"jak", "sex"=>"dfkj", "race"=>"jkadflj", "birthdate"=>"2011-01-01", "employee_contacts"=>{"street"=>"afdjkljadfkl", "city"=>"jadklfjakldfj", "state"=>"fadjlkdf", "zip"=>"32787", "phone_num"=>"567567567", "alt_phone_num"=>"57875875875", "email"=>"dajkjdlkfj@jkj.com", "emergency_contact_first_name"=>"adfjkladjf", "emergency_contact_last_name"=>"adfjkaldf", "emergency_contact_num"=>"784339793"}}, "commit"=>"Add"}

```
Unpermitted parameter: :employee_contacts
```

And so it saves the Employee but not anything associated with their contact information. If I run Employee.last in the Rails console I get a nil value for employee_contact_id. If I try and use the Rails Console to look up Employee_Contact.last or Employee_Contact.all I get an 'unable to autoload constant Employee_Contact, expected employee_contact.rb to define it'.

**UPDATE**

I changed a few things thanks to Anton.

My Employee Contact model now inherits from ApplicationRecord:

```
class EmployeeContact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee, inverse_of: :employee_contact
end
```

I changed the view form in the employee_contact loop from plural to singular:

```
<%= form.fields_for :employee_contact do |builder| %>
```

I added a build method in Employee#New

```
def new
  @employee = Employee.new
  @employee.build_employee_contact
end
```

And edited Employee#Create

```
def create
  @employee = current_user.employees.create(employee_params)

  if @employee.valid?
  redirect_to root_path
    else
  render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

This is now saving an Employee Contact. Here are the results from the console:

```
#<EmployeeContact id: 1, street: "dafjkafdjl", city: "adjfklajdk", state: "dfjkljalkdfjioad", zip: "dafjadlkfjkajdkl", phone_num: "adf", alt_phone_num: "871274892174", email: "dafnajdklj@jkklda.com", emergency_contact_first_name: "ajdfjalkj", emergency_contact_last_name: "fjadkljdfkl", emergency_contact_num: "11287244", user_id: nil, employee_id: 1, created_at: "2017-10-03 19:01:55", updated_at: "2017-10-03 19:01:55">

Employee id: 1, first_name: "dafad", middle: "dfad", last_name: "dafd", sex: "adfd", race: "dfad", birthdate: "1210-01-01", user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-10-03 19:01:55", updated_at: "2017-10-03 19:01:55", employee_contact_id: nil>
```

The Employee model is still getting an Employee_Contact_Id: nil value. However, the Employee Contact model is getting the correct Employee_Id attribute.

**SOLVED**

So I'm going to leave it at with what I have posted in the Update. There is no need for my Employee model to have an Employee_Contact_Id attribute. When I create a new Employee the Contact correctly maps to that Employee currently.

Comment: Try changing in the strong params employee_contact to employee_contacs_attributes: []

Comment: Why are doing create and then save! in the create action?

Comment: I see that employee has one employee contact.. so you probably need to change the form to :employee_contact

Comment: changing it to employee_contacts_attributes:[] still leaves me with 
Unpermitted parameter: :employee_contacts.

As far as the save! I was trying to see if I could get more information out of the server response. I still get the same Unpermitted parameter :employee_contacts if I change it to if @employee.valid?

Comment: @Anton If I change the form to  `<%= form.fields_for :employee_contact do |builder| %>` the form doesn't build in the form inputs for the Contact model. 

If I go back into the Employee_Controller new method and change it to this
    `def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @employee.build_employee_contact
  end`

I get: unknown attribute 'employee_id' for EmployeeContact.

Comment: Few questions :) 1. Why your employee_contact inheriting from employee and not ApplicationRecord? 2. Do you really have employee_contact.rb file? 3. Why trying to do Employee_Contact.all and not EmpoyeeContact.all?

Comment: @Anton I changed the Employee_Contact model to inherit from ApplicationRecord so now Employee_Contact is now saving. Yes I have an employee_contact.rb file. 

The Employee_Contact now properly maps with the Employee model. However, the employee_contact_id attribute on Employee model still shows -nil-.

I will update my original post

Comment: Now try to build the employee contact from the employee in the new action.

Comment: @Anton -- Updated my post. Listed what I am getting now. Only issue I am having is getting the Employee model to get a value for the Employee Contact Id attribute. Not sure if that even matters if an Employee only has 1 employee_contact

Comment: Can you do in the rails c: @employee =  Employee.new and @employee.employee_contact.build? What are getting?

Comment: @Anton `NoMethodError: undefined method build' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):2` is what I get when using @employee.employee_contact.build
The current build method that I posted in the Update works totally fine.

Comment: Yeah.. my mistake.. its a has_one. @employee.build_employee_contact this is the correct one. What are you getting with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the EmployeeContact to inherit from ApplicationRecord, not Employee.
In the new action build the employee contact for the nested form from the employee.
I would suggest to remove the foreign key from the has_one association.
The employee_id on the employee_contact is enough.